# Non-zero `\itemindent` with properly aligned `enumerate` labels and without the `enumitem` package

Tags: lists

I would like to indent the first line of list items in `enumerate`. To do this,
I have defined several kinds of `enumerate`-like environments (see below).

In `enumerateI`, I just use a non-zero `\itemindent`. All the labels are then
moved to the right compared to the standard `enumerate`. The distance between
"2." and "(a)" on line "ZZZ" is wrong too.

In `enumerateII`, I add `\itemindent` to `\labelsep`. Labels on lines "XXX",
"YYY" and "WWW" are then at the same position as with `enumerate`, but the "(a)"
on line "ZZZ" is not vertically aligned with the "(a)" and "(b)" on lines "YYY"
and "WWW".

In `enumerateIII`, I set `\itemindent` to 0 if `@noparlist` is true. The 
alignment of "(a)" on line "ZZZ is now correct, but this time, "WWW" is not
indented anymore and "(b)" is not vertically aligned with the "(a)"'s.

[Note: I have tested `@noparlist`, but I don't understand how this switch 
differs from `@inlabel` and `@noparitem`. LaTeX's "source2e" is quite obscure 
about this, so if someone could clarify the meaning of these switches, I would 
really appreciate that. Should this be a separate question? Anyway, in the cases considered here, it makes no difference.]

I have also tried to modify the lines containing `\itemindent` in the 
definition of `\@item` from "latex.ltx", but without success.

So, my question is the following: how to get the same alignment as with 
`enumerateII` on lines "XXX", "YYY" and "WWW", and the same as with 
`enumerateIII` on line "ZZZ"? I know that similar questions have already been 
asked before, but I would like an **automatic** solution **not** using the `enumitem` package. Redefining `\@item` is acceptable, if not too daring.

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter

\newlength\standardlabelsep
\setlength\standardlabelsep{5pt}
\newlength\myitemindent
\setlength\myitemindent{\parindent}

\newenvironment{enumerateI}{%
  \begin{enumerate}%
    \setlength\itemindent{\myitemindent}%
    \setlength\labelsep{\standardlabelsep}%
  }{\end{enumerate}}

\newenvironment{enumerateII}{%
  \begin{enumerate}%
    \setlength\itemindent{\myitemindent}%
    \setlength\labelsep{\standardlabelsep}%
    \addtolength\labelsep{\itemindent}%
  }{\end{enumerate}}

\newenvironment{enumerateIII}{%
  \begin{enumerate}%
    \setlength\itemindent{\myitemindent}%
    \setlength\labelsep{\standardlabelsep}%
    \addtolength\labelsep{\myitemindent}%
    \if@noparlist
       \setlength\itemindent{0pt}%
    \fi
  }{\end{enumerate}}

\newcommand\XXX{XXX\dotfill\break xxx\dotfill\hfill}
\newcommand\YYY{YYY\dotfill\break yyy\dotfill\hfill}
\newcommand\ZZZ{ZZZ\dotfill\break zzz\dotfill\hfill}
\newcommand\WWW{WWW\dotfill\break www\dotfill\hfill}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

Standard \verb|enumerate|:
\begin{enumerate}
\item
  \XXX
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item
    \YYY
  \end{enumerate}
\item
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item
    \ZZZ
  \item
    \WWW
  \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\verb|enumerateI|:
\begin{enumerateI}
\item
  \XXX
  \begin{enumerateI}
  \item
    \YYY
  \end{enumerateI}
\item
  \begin{enumerateI}
  \item
    \ZZZ
  \item
    \WWW
  \end{enumerateI}
\end{enumerateI}

\verb|enumerateII|:
\begin{enumerateII}
\item
  \XXX
  \begin{enumerateII}
  \item
    \YYY
  \end{enumerateII}
\item
  \begin{enumerateII}
  \item
    \ZZZ
  \item
    \WWW
  \end{enumerateII}
\end{enumerateII}

\verb|enumerateIII|:
\begin{enumerateIII}
\item
  \XXX
  \begin{enumerateIII}
  \item
    \YYY
  \end{enumerateIII}
\item
  \begin{enumerateIII}
  \item
    \ZZZ
  \item
    \WWW
  \end{enumerateIII}
\end{enumerateIII}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Enclose nested list in `minipage`, something like this: `\begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth-\itemindent-\leftmargini} \begin{{enumerateII} ... \end{enumerateII}  \end{minipage}`. For this you need add package `calc` in document preamble.

Comment: `list` in minipage` have different margins, see the `latex.ltx` 'manual' ;-)

Comment: IIRC, enumarate uses \leftskip and \llap to implement the indentation.  Each layer simply increases \leftskip.

Comment: @Zarko Enclosing nested lists in `minipage` is not an _automatic_ solution. I would prefer to use the standard LaTeX syntax but redefine `enumerate` and, if needed, `\@item`. To do this, I would need to understand how this macro works, in particular the meaning of the switches `@inlabel`, `@noparitem` and `@noparlist`...

Comment: Why don't you like **enumitem**?

Comment: I have nothing against `enumitem`. I would just prefer to implement my own customizations. I agree, however, that it might be simpler to use `enumitem` than trying to tweak `\@item`. Still, I think that others may be interested in how the standard macros for lists work in LaTeX...

Answer (score 1):

With `enumitem`, the best I could find is the answer to [Custom enumerate margin with enumitem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/146846/custom-enumerate-margin-with-enumitem/147443#147443) . Unfortunately, "`[before=\trickindent]`" has to be inserted by hand after an inner `\begin{enumerate}` every time the latter is the first thing following `\item`. Another problem is that the label is shifted horizontally compared to the case where `\itemindent` is zero.

Without `enumitem`, a solution is to modify `\@item` as in the code below. The modified version, `\modified@item`, differs from the original one in that `\itemindent` is not inserted inside the label box but at the end of the `\everypar` (I hope this is the right place). After `\let\@item\modified@item`, both `enumerate` and `itemize` are modified. Because of the "`\ifdim`...", this happens only if `\itemindent` is positive, so environments such as `description` or `verse` are untouched. This seems to work, but there may be side effects if other environments than `enumerate` and `itemize` are wrongly modified.

Note: I won't accept my answer, in case someone comes with a better one.

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter

\def\modified@item[#1]{%
  \if@noparitem
    \@donoparitem
  \else
    \if@inlabel
      \indent \par
    \fi
    \ifhmode
      \unskip\unskip \par
    \fi
    \if@newlist
      \if@nobreak
        \@nbitem
      \else
        \addpenalty\@beginparpenalty
        \addvspace\@topsep
        \addvspace{-\parskip}%
      \fi
    \else
      \addpenalty\@itempenalty
      \addvspace\itemsep
    \fi
    \global\@inlabeltrue
  \fi
  \everypar{%
    \@minipagefalse
    \global\@newlistfalse
    \if@inlabel
      \global\@inlabelfalse
      {\setbox\z@\lastbox
       \ifvoid\z@
         \kern-\itemindent
       \fi}%
      \box\@labels
      \penalty\z@
    \fi
    \if@nobreak
      \@nobreakfalse
      \clubpenalty \@M
    \else
      \clubpenalty \@clubpenalty
      \everypar{}%
    \fi
    \ifdim\itemindent>\z@\kern\itemindent\fi % Added.
  }%
  \if@noitemarg
    \@noitemargfalse
    \if@nmbrlist
      \refstepcounter\@listctr
    \fi
  \fi
  \sbox\@tempboxa{\makelabel{#1}}%
  \global\setbox\@labels\hbox{%
    \unhbox\@labels
    \ifdim\itemindent>\z@\else\hskip \itemindent\fi % Original without `\ifdim`.
    \hskip -\labelwidth
    \hskip -\labelsep
    \ifdim \wd\@tempboxa >\labelwidth
      \box\@tempboxa
    \else
      \hbox to\labelwidth {\unhbox\@tempboxa}%
    \fi
    \hskip \labelsep}%    
  \ignorespaces}

\newlength\standardlabelsep
\setlength\standardlabelsep{5pt}
\newlength\myitemindent
\setlength\myitemindent{\parindent}

\newenvironment{enumerateI}{%
  \begin{enumerate}%
    \setlength\itemindent{\myitemindent}%
    \setlength\labelsep{\standardlabelsep}%
  }{\end{enumerate}}

\newcommand\XXX{XXX\dotfill\break xxx\dotfill\hfill}
\newcommand\YYY{YYY\dotfill\break yyy\dotfill\hfill}
\newcommand\ZZZ{ZZZ\dotfill\break zzz\dotfill\hfill}
\newcommand\WWW{WWW\dotfill\break www\dotfill\hfill}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\verb|enumerate| with the original \verb|\@item|:
\begin{enumerate}
\item
  \XXX
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item
    \YYY
  \end{enumerate}
\item
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item
    \ZZZ
  \item
    \WWW
  \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\verb|enumerateI| with the original \verb|\@item|:
\begin{enumerateI}
\item
  \XXX
  \begin{enumerateI}
  \item
    \YYY
  \end{enumerateI}
\item
  \begin{enumerateI}
  \item
    \ZZZ
  \item
    \WWW
  \end{enumerateI}
\end{enumerateI}

\verb|description| with the original \verb|\@item|:
\begin{description}
\item[AAA.]
  \XXX
  \begin{description}
  \item[BBB.]
    \YYY
  \end{description}
\item[CCC.]
  \begin{description}
  \item[DDD.]
    \ZZZ
  \item[EEE.]
    \WWW
  \end{description}
\end{description}

\makeatletter
\let\@item\modified@item
\makeatother

\verb|enumerate| with the modified \verb|\@item|:
\begin{enumerate}
\item
  \XXX
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item
    \YYY
  \end{enumerate}
\item
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item
    \ZZZ
  \item
    \WWW
  \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\verb|enumerateI| with the modified \verb|\@item|:
\begin{enumerateI}
\item
  \XXX
  \begin{enumerateI}
  \item
    \YYY
  \end{enumerateI}
\item
  \begin{enumerateI}
  \item
    \ZZZ
  \item
    \WWW
  \end{enumerateI}
\end{enumerateI}

\verb|description| with the modified \verb|\@item|:
\begin{description}
\item[AAA.]
  \XXX
  \begin{description}
  \item[BBB.]
    \YYY
  \end{description}
\item[CCC.]
  \begin{description}
  \item[DDD.]
    \ZZZ
  \item[EEE.]
    \WWW
  \end{description}
\end{description}

\end{document}
```